# Trying to call a method within an if else.. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: java, function, if-statement, methods

I'm writing a program that, for sake of ease, I would like to call a function from within an if/if else. 
I keep getting the message "non-static method select1() cannot be referenced from a static context".

Sample of code: If else, leading to method:

```
option = input.nextInt();

if (option == 1){select1();}
if (option == 2) {System.out.println("boo");}
if (option == 3) {System.out.println("hehe");}
else {System.out.println("blahh");}

   }


}

static void main select1();{

System.out.println("");};
```

I'm relatively new at programming, so any help would be great!

Comment: `select()` needs to be declared `static` for you to be able to call it from `main()`. Just like the error message says. It has nothing to do with `if-else`. And what is this -> `static void main select1();{` ??

Comment: `static void main select1();{` what are you trying to do here? Which of this part should be name of your method? What is the purpose if `main` here? Why there is `;` after `select1()`?

Comment: The way you're declaring your method is a syntax error - you introduce duplicate named identifiers and introduce a semi-colon after the parentheses.

Comment: Is there anyway I can jump to that method from the if else?

Comment: I think you need to take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

This is illegal:

```
public class MyClass  {
   public void doSomething()  {
      //...
   }
   public static void doSomethingStatically()  {
      doSomething();
   }
}
```

Because `doSomething()` is non-static, and must therefore be tied to a specific instance.

Fix it with either this:

```
public class MyClass  {
   public static void doSomething()  {
      //...
   }
   public static void doSomethingStatically()  {
      doSomething();
   }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class MyClass  {
   public void doSomething()  {
      //...
   }
   public static void doSomethingStatically()  {
      (new MyClass()).doSomething();
   }
}
```

Comment: @user3071724: if this answer has helped you, please consider up-voting and accepting it as your answer by clicking on the big green checkmark. Best of luck and welcome to stackoverflow!